# Como adicionar diretórios para a busca de módulos em Lua?

Tags: lua, require

Eu estou tendo um problema com a função require, eu quero que ela procure um arquivo lua, mas não quero especificar a pasta, e meu lua esta instalado em outro disco, vou colocar uma foto para verem o erro[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver a parte destacada eh o arquivo que quero usar, está na pasta lib ali no canto, dei um cd C:\ no terminal para testar umas coisas e vi que esta dando esse erro, acho que eu so tenho que especificar o disco, porém eu não quero especificar a pasta pois no computador de outra pessoa não ira funcionar, por que a pasta tera nome diferente, então como posso fazer?

Comment: Você não deveria especificar apenas o caminho relativo do arquivo, no caso `Lib\\BibliotecaPadrao`?

Comment: sim e fiz isso, porem ele da o mesmo erro q eu acho q eh prq so procura no mesmo drive do lua instalado, e eh por isso que eu perguntei se tem como falar que eu quero q procure nos dois drives ou so no C:\

Answer (score 1):

O Lua busca os módulos usando a variável `package.path` a qual por sua vez é iniciada lendo uma variável do sistema chamada `LUA_PATH`.

Para adicionar um novo lugar para a busca de módulos basta você alterar uma dessas variáveis.

Se você quiser que a pasta esteja sempre disponível você vai querer editar o `LUA_PATH`.

No Windows vc deve ir em Sistema | Configurações Avançadas do Sistema | Variáveis de ambiente e adicionar o `LUA_PATH` ou editar se ela já existir. No Linux vc vai colocar esse setup no seu `.bashrc`.

Ex:

```
LUA_PATH = ;;D:\libs\lua\?.lua
```

O `;;` no início faz o lua carregar as libs default no inicio do path. Note que tem uma interrogação `?` no pattern. Ela serve para marcar o lugar onde vai entrar o que vc digitar no require.

Ex: Considere essa estrutura de diretórios:

```
D:
|- libs
    |- lua
        |- math
            |- linearAlgebra.lua
```

Com o `LUA_PATH` definido como acima vc pode fazer assim no teu código lua:

```
local la = require "math.linearAlgebra"
local v = la.dot({1, 0}, {1, 2})
...
```

A convenção é usar um ponto `.` onde haveria um separador de diretório (por isso `math.linearAlgebra` e não `math\\linearAlgebra`)

E repare também que o `.lua` não é especificado pois o mesmo já foi definido no `LUA_PATH`.

Se vc quiser adicionar mais padrões de busca, basta separá-los com `;`.

E por fim é importante saber que tudo isso também vale para o `package.path`.